# Upload React JS app front-end only

Tags: reactjs, redux, hosting, frontend

I have created a succesfully working React JS / Redux application on localhost. Now it is time to upload my app. The application is basicly a logger and a complicated line of calculations which runs on front-end. There are no saved datas, once the user refresh the browser the app re-starts. The app relies on several libs as boostrap in react, Redux, Modal, DOM to image saver etc.

How does one migrate such an application for web? Would You upload like a classical static HTML site + the compiled script? Or does the entire file structure must be uploaded to the hosting provider.

Thanks,
Koppany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of uploading/hosting such an app.

1. Use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and bundle all your code. You will get two output files

   - `index.html`
   - `app.js`

   You can then upload them to services like [surge](https://surge.sh/)

   [Note:-] **More** files can be generated depending upon your webpack configurations. But the basic idea is the same. Upload them **all** to the hosting service (like surge).
2. You can upload your code to [codepen](https://codepen.io/). You can then specify external dependencies in codepen and so codepen will take care of it.

Comment: I have found the way. For me the easiest solution was that download the JS index file from localhost running project, than recreate with the materials. and Succes!
Thanks anyway!